# Argument 1 passed to must be of the type string, array given

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a TYPO3 php function to get a preselected categories,
The error generated in frontend say that it should be a String but an array is given:

```
Argument 1 passed to Web\Auf\Controller\ResultsController::getPreselectedCategories() must be of the type string, array given, called in /app/Private/typo3conf/ext/auf/Classes/Controller/DemandRequestTrait.php on line 93
```

The part of the code called :

```
    protected function getPreselectedStandardCategories(): array
{
    return $this->getPreselectedCategories($this->settings['filter']['category']['preselected'] ?? '');
}
```

Please forgive if this is not clear ask me to explain more or to fix.

Comment: Seems to me that your $this->settings['filter']['category']['preselected'] holds and array and not a string.

Comment: Maybe also share/post here the method getPreselectedCategories()

Comment: Can you give us the content of TypoScript plugin.tx_youplugin.filter.category.preselected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers.
The issue was due to wrong Flexform configuration stored in the database,
When the backend user change the type of content element the flexform still stored.
I have deleted the content element and i have created a new one. This fixed my problem.